# How To Set The value after Unset in php

Tags: php, arrays

what i  Need

- i  Need to Retain the array values after unset them first.

Here is the array structure( Before unset)

```
    [0] => Array
    (
        [currency] => INR
    )

   [1] => Array
    (
        [type] => General Public Tickets  Adult
        [amount] => 50
        [comment] => (Working Days)
    )
   [2] => Array
    (
        [type] => General Public Tickets  Adult
        [amount] => 80
        [comment] => (Saturday/ Sunday/ Holiday)
    )
```

Here is the array structure( After unset)

```
    [1] => Array
    (
        [type] => General Public Tickets  Adult
        [amount] => 50
        [comment] => (Working Days)
    )
   [2] => Array
    (
        [type] => General Public Tickets  Adult
        [amount] => 80
        [comment] => (Saturday/ Sunday/ Holiday)
    )
```

here is the php code

```
                   unset($data[0]);
                 /* code to set the value after unset */
                   $data= array_values($data[0]);
```

- i Need  currency to be put in another array
- first i  have unset the array value [currency] from the array.
- then i want  [currency] to  be put in another array.
- how  could i set the value after unset from array.

Comment: impossible, you need to do it the other way round

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//save element to a new variable
$temp = $data[0];

//unset element
unset($data[0]);

/* code to set the value after unset */

//add element back to the array
$data[0] = $temp;
        OR
//To add elements to the beginning of an array, use array_unshift
array_unshift($data,$temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get currency value before unset it in new array. If you unset and after that you try to access it then it will cause for **undefined**

Try like this:

```
             $arrNew = $data[0];  //save it new array
              unset($data[0]); //unset it now
```